# fillna() with map(dict) fills not only NaNs, but all values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame called `data` with some columns. One of them is `Married` and another one is `Gender`. Both variables are categorical.

```
>>> print(data[['Gender', 'Married']].dtypes)
Gender     category
Married    category
dtype: object
```

`Married` contains no `NaN` values, but `Gender` contains 12 `NaN` values, **which I want to impute**.

```
>>> print(data['Gender'].isna().sum())
12
```

I've made quick analysis that if you have `Married='Yes'`, then you're much more likely to have `Gender='Male'`. So I want to impute `Gender` values in such manner:

```
Married='Yes' ->  Gender='Male'
Married='No'  ->  Gender='Female'
```

So I created a dictionary:

```
dictionary = {'Yes': 'Male', 'No': 'Female'}
```

Then I wrote a simple code based on `fillna()`:

```
data['Gender'].fillna(data['Married'].map(dictionary), inplace=True)
```

And it worked... in totally different way then expected. It changed the whole `Gender` column! Every single entry now is based on `Married` column. Look at these crosstabs:

**Before fillna()**:

```
Married   No  Yes
Gender           
Female    80   31
Male     129  352
```

**After fillna()**:

```
Married   No  Yes
Gender           
Female   212    0
Male       0  392
```

What can I do to fill NaN `Gender` values basing on `Married` column?

Comment: Tested with categoricals and working nice.

Comment: yeah, I tested on a different set and the same code worked perfectly... I think it's just a pandas bug or maybe fillna() needs to meet some assumptions, which I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks fine. If it doesn't work, there may be a Pandas bug. You can try `loc` assignment with Boolean indexing instead:

```
mask = df['Gender'].isnull()
df.loc[mask, 'Gender'] = df.loc[mask, 'Married'].map(dictionary)
```

Comment: @jezrael, It fails for me on Pandas v0.19.2. This could be a version specific bug.

Comment: @jpp - Do you test is with categoricals?

Comment: @jezrael, ..Yes

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), which returns values from a `choicelist` depending on the results of the conditions:

```
n = df.Gender.isna()
m1 = n & (df.Married == 'Yes')
m2 = n & (df.Married == 'No')
np.select([m1,m2], ['Male','Female'], default=df.Gender)
```

Comment: If big DataFrame, you could make the first mask `df.Gender.isna()` only once, and combine it with another after :)

Comment: True! Updated with your suggestion :)

Comment: Thanks! It's good way around, I didn't think of np.select(). Now it works :)

Comment: Note the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) have `default` as an optional **scalar**. Are you sure this works?

Comment: Yes @jpp, I also tested it

Comment: @yatu, You're right, it does indeed work. Maybe the docs  need updating :)